# Calibrating contrast and colour on monitor fails. 

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a program that I use to calibrate my computer monitor for color and contrast.  When I run the program, the monitor fails to reset back to normal and all the icons are large and distorted.  I am forced to reboot to reset the monitor appearance.  Any clue what the problem may be?  I have spoken to the software manufacturer, they suggested it was driver. My graphics card is a ATI Radeon HD5670 1GB GDDR5.

Answer (score 1):

The windows 7 system has a color calibration utility built in , that will create a color profile the system will use with that monitor. In the control panel go to "display" and use the "Calibrate color" item on the left.

The problem sounds like the program your using, is using its own "screen" like a game would use its own screen, instead of a "window". The program is setting a low res, or setting the system to a lower res, and when departing the program the res it not set back proper.  (just guessing from your description).

The windows own color calibration tools runs "windowed" and does not change the resolution of the display to run the program.   It has adequate capability to pull off a visual color calibration. Although it does not have a seperate hardware color sencor, like some very high end color calibration instruments.

The problem your getting could be a driver, but from your limited description It could be a software+driver problem, a software only issue, or a compatability issue, or numbers of other things.